# How to get the sum per month of this mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, greatest-n-per-group

My MySQL table looks like this:

```
date              value
2014-08-13 08:00  12
2014-08-13 09:00  38
2014-08-13 10:00  64
2014-08-14 08:00  7
2014-08-14 09:00  19
2014-08-14 10:00  41
```

I want to get the sum of month 8, only adding the highest value. E.g. here 105 (64 + 41)
Can I get this with only one MySQL query?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - you want to sum the highest values per day for the entire month, right?

Comment: here 64,41 are in separate column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(t1.value)
from your_table t1
join
(
  select max(datetime_column) as mdate
  from your_table
  group by date(datetime_column)
) t2 on t1.datetime_column = t2.mdate
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5ca4/5)